# Render multiple partial views with the same model in one request

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Suppose I have 3 partial views, that all take in the same model and similarly should be rendered/updated at the same time. i.e.

```
<div id="Partial_view1">
    @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("partialview1", Model); }
</div>
<div class="Partial_view2">
    @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("partialview2", Model); }
</div>
<div class="Partial_view3">
    @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("partialview3", Model); }
</div>
```

Currently, when I want to update a partial view with jQuery and AJAX, I normally call the following function with respectively the parent div, url and potentially an ID:

```
var updatePartialView = function (url, data, hook) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        data: data,
        success: function (response) {
            hook.html(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Could look something like this:

```
helper.updatePartialView('/Controller', 2, $('#Partial_view1'))
```

The controller would then normally return a partialview result, where naturally a partial view and a model is returned, which i nest below the containing div of the partial view.

```
//From controller
return PartialView("partialview1", Model);
```

I want to reduce the payload towards my server, thus I'm not interested in doing 3 almost identical calls.. Hence why I want to understand, if there is some sort of way in which I can just fetch the model from the controller, and then populate the 3 partial views in jquery.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you using Partial Views if it's the same model?  And what prevents you from just getting whatever model data you need from the Controller since you want to do it via AJAX?  I guess I'm saying...I'm not understanding your problem.

Comment: I guess you don't need three partial views here. Since it is the same model, use just one partial view which combines all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your three partial views are in the same page,so you just use `return View("MainPage",model)` to update the main page with the updated model instead of using `return PartialView("PartialViewName",model)`.

But this way have a disadvantage,if you use Layout in your razor view.It will display repeated the navbar.

Index.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<Test>
<div id="view_all">
    <div id="Partial_view1">
        @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("partialview1", Model); }
    </div>
    <div class="Partial_view2">
        @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("partialview2", Model); }
    </div>
    <div class="Partial_view3">
        @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("partialview3", Model); }
    </div>
    <input type="button" onclick="Update()" value="Update" />
</div>
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        function Update() {
            updatePartialView('/Home/Update', 2)
        }    
        var updatePartialView = function (url, data) {
            $.ajax({
                url: url+"?id="+data,
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#view_all').html(response);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private List<Test> model = new List<Test>()
        {
            //....
        };

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(model);
    }
    public IActionResult Update(int id)
    {
        //change the model by yourself
        var test2 = model.Where(a=>a.Id==id).FirstOrDefault();
        test2.Number = 9;
        model[0].Test1.Category = "aaaaaaaa";
        model[2].Test2.Age = "34343434";

        return View("Index", model);
    }
}
```

**The second option** I think you could custom a `RenderRazorViewToString` function which could parse view to string  and did like below:

Model:

```
public class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public Test1 Test1 { get; set; }        
    public Test2 Test2 { get; set; }        
}
public class Test1
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
public class Test2
{
    public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<Test>
//...
<input type="button" onclick="Update()" value="Update" />

@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        function Update() {
            updatePartialView('/Home/Update', 2)
        }
        
        var updatePartialView = function (url, data) {
            $.ajax({
                url: url+"?id="+data,
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#Partial_view1').html(response.view1);
                    $('.Partial_view2').html(response.view2);
                    $('.Partial_view3').html(response.view3);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
}
```

partialview1.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<Test>
<h1>Test</h1>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Number)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Number)
                </td> 
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>               
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

partialview2.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<Test>
<h1>Test1</h1>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Test1.Category)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Test1.Category)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

partialview3.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<Test>
<h1>Test2</h1>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Test2.Age)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Test2.Age)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Update(int id)
{
    //change your model by yourself
   
    //pass the updated model to the partial view
    var view1 = Helper.RenderRazorViewToString(this, "partialview1", model);
    var view2 = Helper.RenderRazorViewToString(this, "partialview2", model);
    var view3 = Helper.RenderRazorViewToString(this, "partialview3", model);
    return Json(new { view1 = view1, view2 = view2, view3 = view3 });
}
```

RenderRazorViewToString method:

```
public class Helper
{
    public static string RenderRazorViewToString(Controller controller, string viewName, object model = null)
    {
        controller.ViewData.Model = model;
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            IViewEngine viewEngine =
                controller.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(ICompositeViewEngine)) as
                    ICompositeViewEngine;
            ViewEngineResult viewResult = viewEngine.FindView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName, false);

            ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(
                controller.ControllerContext,
                viewResult.View,
                controller.ViewData,
                controller.TempData,
                sw,
                new HtmlHelperOptions()
            );
            viewResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext);
            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

By the way,the three patial views depend on the same model,why did you put them together as one partial view?

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer. Its a valid point moving all of it to 1 partialview.. However, this may not be feasible due to various different reasons. I will consider though, cause even though you proposed some working solutions, I don't feel that any of them are optimal